Compare two meta key values with between value
Records in CPT are as follow



Name
Size From
Size To




Demo 1
900
6000


Demo 2
5000
6000


Demo 3
7500
12000


Demo 4
2500
7500


Demo 5
9000
12000



$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        array(
            'key' => '_size',
            'value'    =>  array(1000, 5000),
            'type'     => 'decimal(10, 2)',
            'compare'  => 'between'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_size_to',
            'value'    =>  array(1000, 5000),
            'type'     => 'decimal(10, 2)',
            'compare'  => 'between'
        ),
    ),
);

After applying above meta_query not able to get actual output
Expected Output



Name
Size From
Size To




Demo 1
900
6000


Demo 2
5000
6000


Demo 4
2500
7500



Actually it's working like below SQL's. Please review once and let me know best fit for this situation.
Right Now
SELECT * FROM test WHERE _size BETWEEN (1000 AND 5000) OR _size_to BETWEEN (1000 AND 5000)

Trying to do like below
SELECT * FROM test WHERE 1000 BETWEEN (_size AND _size_to) OR 5000 BETWEEN (_size AND _size_to)


I don't understand the last sql query ... 1000 BETWEEN (_size AND _size_to) .... edit your question to explain in english the result you want.

This query selects all rows from the test table where either 1000 or 5000 falls within the range defined by the size and size_to columns.

Your question and code attempt is totally unclear regarding your desired expected results: It seems that you want simply to get results where _size is smaller or equal to 5000… For that, you should only keep the _size array with 'value' => 5000 and 'compare' => '<='… Also remove  'relation' => 'OR' code line.

Here I compared below conditions,
The value of the _size field must be less than or equal to 5000.
The value of the _size_to field must be greater than or equal to 1000.
When we filter like Min[1000] & Max[12000]
_size <= 1000
_size_to >= 5000

<?php
$filter_size_rang_min_val = 1000;
$filter_size_rang_max_val = 5000;

$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key' => '_size',
        'value'    =>  $filter_size_rang_max_val,
        'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare' => '<='
    ),
    array(
        'key' => '_size_to',
        'value'    =>  $filter_size_rang_min_val,
        'type'     => 'NUMERIC',
        'compare'  => '>='
    ),
);

